# Slick2D runnable jar (JarSplice) cannot find sound asset? "Resource not found" error

Tags: exception, audio, jar, resources, slick2d

I just started making a Slick2D game yesterday, and everything was going fine until I added sound. The game itself works fine within eclipse, and the sound plays as expected. However, when I compile it into a jar file and then into a fat jar with JarSplice, the resulting runnable jar opens the game window for a fraction of a second and then crashes. If I run the jar from a command prompt I can see that the error returned is:

ERROR:Resource not found: Assets/sound/THRUST.wav
Java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource not found: Assets/sound/THRUST.wav

...and so on. I've checked the jar file and all the sound files were successfully added. I've also tried building the jar without the code for sound, and it works fine, so the image assets are loading correctly. It only has the issue with sound assets. This is my code:

```
package starMiner;

import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.BasicGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;


import org.newdawn.slick.*;


public class StarMiner extends BasicGame
{
  static AppGameContainer app;
  static int resX=800;
  static int resY=600;
  Image bg = null;
  Image playerShip = null;
  Image shipMove = null;
  Image shipIdle = null;
  float x = 0;
  float y = 0;
  float scale = 1.0f;
  float xMomentum = 0;
  float yMomentum = 0;
  float speed = 0;
  Sound fuel,engine;


  public StarMiner()
  {
     super("StarMiner");
  }

  @Override
  public void init(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException
  {
      bg = new Image("Assets/stars.png");
      playerShip = new Image("Assets/starship.png");
      shipIdle = new Image("Assets/starship.png");
      shipMove = new Image("Assets/starshipgo.png");
      fuel = new Sound("Assets/sound/THRUST.wav");
      engine = new Sound("Assets/sound/engine.wav");

  }

  @Override
  public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta) throws SlickException
  {
      Input input = gc.getInput();

      if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT))
      {
          playerShip.rotate(-0.1f * delta);
      }

      if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_ESCAPE))
      {
          app.exit();
      }

      if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_F4))
      {
          app.setFullscreen(!app.isFullscreen());
      }

      if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT))
      {
          playerShip.rotate(0.1f * delta);
      }

      if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP))
      {
          playerShip.setTexture(shipMove.getTexture());
          float hip = 0.4f * delta;

          float rotation = playerShip.getRotation();

          xMomentum+= hip * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation));
          yMomentum-= hip * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation));
          if(!fuel.playing()){fuel.play();}
      }
      else
      {
          fuel.stop();
          playerShip.setTexture(shipIdle.getTexture());
      }

      if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN))
      {
          float hip = 0.4f * delta;

          float rotation = playerShip.getRotation();

          xMomentum-= hip * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation));
          yMomentum+= hip * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation));
      }
      x+=xMomentum/800;
      y+=yMomentum/800;


      xMomentum-=(xMomentum)/1300;
      yMomentum-=(yMomentum)/1300;
      if(Math.abs(xMomentum)<.000001){xMomentum=0;}
      if(Math.abs(yMomentum)<.000001){yMomentum=0;}

      speed = (float) Math.sqrt((0-xMomentum)*(0-xMomentum) + (0-yMomentum)*(0-yMomentum));
      if(!engine.playing()){engine.play();}

 }

  @Override
  public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException
  {
     int xDif = 640;
     int yDif = 480;
     int pModx = (int) ((x*.8)%xDif);
     int pMody = (int) ((y*.8)%yDif);
     int bgExt = 4*(resX/800);
     for(int i = -(bgExt/2)+1; i <= bgExt/2; i++)
     {
         for(int j = -(bgExt/2)+1; j <= bgExt/2; j++)
         {
             bg.draw(((resX/2)-16)-pModx-(xDif*i), ((resY/2)-16)-pMody-(yDif*j));
         }
     }
     bg.draw(((resX/2)-16)-pModx, ((resY/2)-16)-pMody);
     bg.draw(((resX/2)-16)-pModx-xDif, ((resY/2)-16)-pMody);
     bg.draw(((resX/2)-16)-pModx-xDif, ((resY/2)-16)-pMody-yDif);
     bg.draw(((resX/2)-16)-pModx, ((resY/2)-16)-pMody-yDif);
     playerShip.draw(((resX/2)-16), ((resY/2)-16), scale);
     g.drawString("x: "+x, 10, 50);
     g.drawString("y: "+y, 10, 70);
     g.drawString("xMomentum: "+xMomentum, 10, 90);
     g.drawString("yMomentum: "+yMomentum, 10, 110);
     g.drawString("angle: "+playerShip.getRotation(), 10, 130);
     g.drawString("speed: "+speed, 10, 150);

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws SlickException
  {
     app = new AppGameContainer(new StarMiner());

     app.setDisplayMode(resX, resY, false);
     app.start();
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What if you try putting the Asset folder next to the generate .jar (as in  the same folder as the .jar, NOT inside the .jar)?